# Передача куков на сайт

Tags: c#, cookie, request

Хочу понять, как передать новый куки на сайт.

Я использую локальный сервер и домен, но код , который расположен ниже не работает.

Как можно передать куки на сайт разными способами *(желательно подробно)*?
Вроде должно отсылать, но по факту - нет.

Код ниже:

```
public virtual System.Net.CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; set; }

private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string uri = "http://test/";

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    System.Net.Cookie cook = new System.Net.Cookie("MyName", "rrrrrr", "/", "test");
    request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    request.CookieContainer.Add(cook);


    if ( cook != null )
    {
        textbox.Text = cook.Name + " " + cook.Value;
    }    
}
```

[image: Ошибка]

Comment: Вы `request.CookieContainer` нигде не инициализируете, смотрите примеры на официальном сайте https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Пожалуйста, приводите код текстом, а не картинками.

Comment: @AK добавил код

Comment: @RezzziCTC У вас скриншот с приведенным кодом отличаются, строка с инициализацией `CookieContainer` разные.